# Octave/Matlab: Difference between e^(-1*z) and exp(-1*z)

Tags: matlab, octave

I am new with Octave and I have a problem.I thought the following codes were the same, but they produces different results. What is the difference? Thanks

Octave/Matlab: Difference between e^(-1*z) and exp(-1*z)

g = 1./(1 + e^(-1*z));

g = 1./(1 + exp(-1*z));

Where z is a vector, element or matrix

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### In Octave

`exp(1)` equals [`e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Mathematical-Constants.html#XREFe) where `e` is [*Euler's number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

There are 4 operations/functions that are to be noted here:

`e^x` is same as [`expm(x)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Functions-of-a-Matrix.html#XREFexpm) and `e.^(x)` is same as [`exp(x)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Exponents-and-Logarithms.html#XREFexp).

- `e^x` and `expm(m)` represent `e` raise to the matrix `x`.
- `e.^(x)` and `exp(x)` represent exponential e<sup>x</sup> for each element in matrix `x`.

If `x` is a scalar then all (`e^x`, `expm(x)`, `e.^x` and `exp(x)`) are mathematically equal.
For your case, `z` is a matrix and hence you get different results.

---

### In MATLAB,

`e` is not defined in MATLAB.  [`exp(x)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html) and [`expm(x)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html) have same definitions in MATLAB as those that are described for Octave above.

---

<sub>**PS:** `e` or `E` are also used for [*E-notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) in both MATLAB and Octave but that's a different thing.</sub>

Comment: And then there's `expm(x)`

Answer (score 5):

In Octave, it is important to note that `e^x` and `exp(x)`, where `x` is a double precision scalar variable, are not necessarily the same.

For instance:

```
>> a = e ^ 2
a =  7.3891

>> b = exp (2)
b =  7.3891

>> b - a
ans = 8.8818e-16
```

The reason is that `exp (2)` uses a dedicated algorithm to compute the exponential function, while `e ^ 2` actually calls the function `e ()` to get the value of e, and then squares it:

```
>> c = realpow (e (), 2)
c =  7.3891

>> c - a
ans = 0
```

Another reason why `e ^ x` and `exp (x)` differ is that they compute completely different things when `x` is a square matrix, but this has already been discussed in Sardar's answer.